# Class Derived Iterator

Tags: java, stack, queue

What does it mean for an iterator to be derived from a class?

More specifically, I have two classes DNode and DoublyLinkedList. DoublyLinkedList uses DNode to construct the list and I'm using both to create a stack and queue. How do I write a method which returns a class derived iterator?

Here's what I have currently:

```
public Iterator <E> getCollectionIterator() {

      Iterator <E> i = new Iterator <E>() {

          private int currentIndex = 0;

          @Override
          public boolean hasNext() {
               return (currentIndex < size && arrayList[currentIndex] != null);
          }

          @Override
          public E next() {
               if(hasNext()) {
                  return arrayList[currentIndex++];
               } else
                 throw new NoSuchElementException("Next element does not exist.");
          }        

         @Override
         public void remove() {
               throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not supported");
         }
    };

      return i;
}
```

Comment: If something is "class derived", it means that it's a subclass, i.e. it is derived from the base class. Why they want your iterator to be derived is unknown to us, since we don't have enough information to know that. --- On a side note: How can `DoublyLinkedList` extend `DNode`? A linked list consists of zero-to-many nodes, it doesn't extend a node.

Comment: You're right that was my mistake, DNode is only utilized by DoublyLinkedList. What I'm failing to understand is does class derived mean that the collection which is being iterated over needs to be declared of type DoublyLinkedList?

Comment: *Unrelated:* `if(hasNext() == true)` is better written as `if (hasNext())`. Returning `null` from `next()` violates the contract, see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--): *"Throws `NoSuchElementException` if the iteration has no more elements"*

Comment: Since the DNode is constructing the List you can define your Iterator on DNode class or you can have an Inner class that is defined within DoublyLinkedList ( as a subclass) that will be used to iterate over the DoublyLinkedList. Then you can invoke this Iterator class within the LinkedList, this is how it works by going back and forth on top of the DoublyLinkedList.

Comment: So I need to import linkedlist and override it's iterator interface in order to implement the class derived iterator?

Comment: In above with "class derived iterator" do you mean `E` in your code? Because the iterator is **not** derived by `E`, it is *parameterized* by the type given to `E`.